# Error Running Kibana "JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!"

Tags: environment-variables, kibana, java-home

I have downloaded and extracted the Kibana zip file, and (per the directions on the elasticsearch/kibana and github site fore Kibana) I ran "kibana.bat". When I run this I get the following error message:

"unable to access jarfile ... JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!"

I have the JAVA_HOME variable set. I have no problem running Elasticsearch (which also requires the JAVA_HOME variable to be set)

Any ideas as to what might cause this to occur.

Comment: i have same question, have you found the answer?